# How to define a class in php that accepts unlimited properties directly

Tags: php, laravel, oop

in Laravel model, for instance, a class **User** can be initialized and properties set like below

```
$u =  new User;
$u->name='Name';
```

But if I create a class in PHP like below

```
class X {}

$x = new X;
```

if I try to set other properties like below

```
$x->name='name';
```

I will receive an error telling me that the property name is not defined in class X

My question is how is it done? so that I can create a class and then be able to add properties as whenever the class is initialized even if the property does not already exist in the class

Answer (score 2):

You can use **magic getters & setters from PHP**, methods `__get()` and `__set()`.

```php
class X {
  public function __set($name, $value) {
    $this->$name = $value;
  }
  public function __get($name) {
    return $this->$name;
  }
}

$x = new X();
$x->name = "Guille";
echo $x->name; // Prints Guille
```

Also remember that dynamic properties are [deprecaded on PHP 8.2](https://php.watch/versions/8.2/dynamic-properties-deprecated).

To allow dynamic properties on PHP 8.2 use:

```php
#[AllowDynamicProperties]
class X {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I was not getting the error prior to PHP 8.2 but after I upgraded to PHP 8.2 a few days ago I saw the  errors then i was surprised thinking I had missed something, adding         
`#[AllowDynamicProperties]` solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want an "unlimited" property class, even without defining a class and the contents, then just use `new \stdClass()`:

```php
class A
{
   public $property1;
   public $property2;
   //...
}

// VS

$class = new \stdClass();

$class->property1 = 'abc';
$class->property1000000 = true;
$class->propertyABC = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

But I think you don't want anything like this, you should AVOID using `stdClass` and classes that magically set stuff using `__get` and `__set`, because you MUST know by memory, what it has. It is considered a very BAD practice...

I am not sure why you need to dynamically set stuff, but maybe a `Collection` or an `array` will solve your issue.